# How to add video Transitions while using Surface view?

Tags: android, kotlin, surfaceview, android-camera2, mediarecorder

I have to add the trasition effects like FadeIN / fade out while recording a video using Surface view with Camera2 Api.

Comment: show some code what you've done so far ?

Comment: I have used CaptureRequest.Builder for capturing the video and apply filters using CameraMetadata and now want to apply the transitions

Comment: For more flexibility, consider switching to TextureView preview.